# Creating a table with a money type is giving me this error in sql: ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL:

```
create table rentals
(
RentalID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
VideoID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
DateOfRental DATE NOT NULL,
RentalCost MONEY NULL
);
```

Error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MONEY NULL )' at line 7

Comment: Where did you get the idea that mysql had a `MONEY` datatype?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of MONEY, use DECIMAL(8,2) for example. There is no MONEY type in MySQL.

Comment: Oh ok, I though money was a valid one for SQL! Thanks man!!!

Comment: Every SQL platform differs considerably. Don't presume anything will work without consulting [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html).